# 14.04 mongodb does not start with start command

Tags: 14.04, mongodb

mongodb runs from command line, but when the start mongod command is used it gives the message at the bottom.

If I do `sudo start mongod` I get `mongod start/running, process 1433` but there is nothing running.

Status command gives: `mongod stop/waiting`
Directory permissions are: mongod:mongod

So how can I overcome this?

```
start mongod
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.57" (uid=1000 pid=2221 comm="start mongod ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")
```

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: hey OP try to remove `mongodb-27017.sock` from `/temp`